# Make Edit button function work properly

Tags: javascript

i have the following code:

```
function appendText(){

        var text = document.getElementById('usertext').value;

            if ( document.getElementById('usertext').value ){

                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.className = 'divex';

                var li = document.createElement('li');
                li.setAttribute('id', 'list');  
                div.appendChild(li);

                var texty = document.createTextNode(text);
                var bigdiv = document.getElementById('addedText');

                var editbutton = document.createElement('BUTTON');
                editbutton.setAttribute('id', 'button_click');
                var buttontext = document.createTextNode('Edit');
                editbutton.appendChild(buttontext); 

                bigdiv.appendChild(li).appendChild(texty);
                bigdiv.appendChild(li).appendChild(editbutton);

                editbutton.onclick = makeAreaEditable;
                var makeAreaEditable = function(){

                            var textareaEdit = document.createElement('textarea');
                            textareaEdit.onclick = myFunction;
                            textareaEdit.customProperty = li.value;

                            function myFunction(e){
                                var objLi = e.currentTarget;
                                objLi.value = objLi.customProperty;
                                document.getElementByID("button_click").value = "ok";
                            };
                        };

                document.getElementById('usertext').value = "";   
        }        
};
```

And the following html:

```
             <textarea id="usertext"></textarea>
    <button onClick="appendText()">Add text </button>

    <div id="addedText" style="float:left">
    </div>
```

I want my makeAreaEditable function to work like so: when i click the edit button a textarea will apear with the li.value inside it. so i can edit the text(the button will also change from edit to ok). i want this in pure javascript

Comment: Also You could give us `jsfiddle.net` link it will be the best way to start

Comment: the li will apear after i click the add text button witch will trigger the appendText function. a li with the edit button will apear under the textarea

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vUpSz  here is the link.. so when i press edit i want the value to apear on a textarea on the same line as the edit.. and the edit to transform in ok so i can then make another function to save the edit on every line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated code

function appendText(){

```
        var text = document.getElementById('usertext').value;

            if ( text ){


                var li = document.createElement('li');
                li.setAttribute('id', 'list');
                li.innerHTML=text;
                li.customProperty = text;
                var editbutton = document.createElement('BUTTON');
                editbutton.setAttribute('id', 'button_click');
                editbutton.setAttribute('value','Edit');
                editbutton.innerHTML='Edit';



                var makeAreaEditable = function(){
                            function myFunction(e){
                                var objLi = e.currentTarget;
                                objLi.value = objLi.customProperty;
                                document.getElementById("button_click").value = "ok";
                                document.getElementById("button_click").innerHTML='ok';
                            };
                            var textareaEdit = document.createElement('textarea');
                            textareaEdit.customProperty = li.customProperty;
                            textareaEdit.onclick = myFunction;
                            li.appendChild(textareaEdit);
                        };
                editbutton.onclick = makeAreaEditable;


                var bigdiv = document.getElementById('addedText');
                li.appendChild(editbutton);
                bigdiv.appendChild(li);
                document.getElementById('usertext').value = "";
        }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add 2 elements (click the addtext 2 times) or more, they all have the same id (button_clic). So don't think the code

```
document.getElementByID("button_click").value
```

will work.

2nd you are creating a div element var div and you add li element to that div. But afterwards you do nothing with it because you assign the li direclty to the bigdiv

And with regards to my last comments, you have to create your functions and then afterwards add them to the element. Now you do it the otherway around, you assign a function to an element and then define the function. And you have to add textareaEdit to an element. Otherwise it will never show on page.

your code should look like this

```
function appendText(){

        var text = document.getElementById('usertext').value;

            if ( document.getElementById('usertext').value ){

                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.className = 'divex';

                var li = document.createElement('li');
                li.setAttribute('id', 'list');
                div.appendChild(li);

                var texty = document.createTextNode(text);
                var bigdiv = document.getElementById('addedText');

                var editbutton = document.createElement('BUTTON');
                editbutton.setAttribute('id', 'button_click');
                var buttontext = document.createTextNode('Edit');
                editbutton.appendChild(buttontext);

                var makeAreaEditable = function(){
                            function myFunction(e){
                                var objLi = e.currentTarget;
                                objLi.value = objLi.customProperty;
                                document.getElementByID("button_click").value = "ok";
                            };
                            var textareaEdit = document.createElement('textarea');
                            textareaEdit.customProperty = li.value;
                            textareaEdit.onclick = myFunction;
                            bigdiv.appendChild(li).appendChild(textareaEdit);
                        };
                editbutton.onclick = makeAreaEditable;
                bigdiv.appendChild(li).appendChild(texty);
                bigdiv.appendChild(li).appendChild(editbutton);
                document.getElementById('usertext').value = "";
        }
};
```

Comment: you have to create your functions and then afterwards add them to the element. Now you do it the otherway around, you assign a function to an element and then define the function. And you have to add textareaEdit to an element. Otherwise it will never show on page. See my next answer

Comment: sorry but when look what happens http://jsfiddle.net/kTaGG/ i will need the value of li to be inside the textarea and when I click edit it just appends textareas and i just need one with the li value inside

Comment: This is the generated code when I type d in the textarea and add it <li value="0" id="list">d<button id="button_click">Edit</button></li></div>. So the value of li is 0.

Comment: Look here http://jsfiddle.net/Juwmm/2/ here is the code i've made it in query! i want it to do the same in pure js...

Comment: Doens't do anything when i click edit. Get a referenceerror: event is not defined. But you are confusing  <button> with <input type="button"> see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542000/setting-a-buttons-value-using-javascript

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22820/discussion-between-paul-harbuz-and-roel)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, there were a couple of things...

First, i've changed this line:

```
if ( document.getElementById('usertext').value ){
```

To this:

```
if ( text ).value ){
```

I've added the ID to the button:

```
<button onClick="appendText()" id="button_click">Add text </button>
```

And pushed this line lower:

```
 editbutton.onclick = makeAreaEditable;
```

Workable jsfiddle can you find here:
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Juwmm/)

Comment: this is working fine to me to... jsfiddle.net/vUpSz the makeAreaEditable is the problem..