# Setting button title in HTML to a non-formatted text

Tags: javascript, html, button, text

I have a simple html page

```html
<body>
<button type="button" id="button1" onclick="foo()">Result!</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function foo() {
    var button = document.getElementById("button1");
  }
  </script>
</body>
```

I want to change the button title on click.
The title might include HTML tags and I want it to be presented as is (without formatting).

I've tried the way suggested in **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542000/setting-a-buttons-value-using-javascript)** post and it works great for a regular text. Unfortunately it formats the HTML tags and doesn't present the non-formatted text:

```html
<body>
<button type="button" id="button1" onclick="foo()">Result!</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function foo() {
    var button = document.getElementById("button1");
    button.innerHTML = "<strong>my text</strong>"
  }
  </script>
</body>
```

To be clear, I want the title to be `<strong>my text</strong>` and not **my text**.

So what is the right way to present a non-formatted text inside the button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **innerText** attribute will do the work:

```html
<body>
<button type="button" id="button1" onclick="foo()">Result!</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function foo() {
    var button = document.getElementById("button1");
    button.innerText = "<strong>my text</strong>"
  }
  </script>
</body>
```

**Note:** Firefox doesn't support innerText, but has its own property called **textContent**, which can be used instead.