# How can I set button content from script?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make todolist where I can add new tasks to do with same functionality as default ones (clickable task with 'delete' button next to it). My current code is creating new button, but it's only empty, grey rectangle, without any content (but it works as it should - it's deleting selected task) - how can I set content of new buttons as "delete"?

SNIPPET

```js
function createListElement() {
     var li = document.createElement("li");
     var span = document.createElement("span");//create span
     var button1 = document.createElement("button");//create button
     span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value)); //assign value to span
     span.classList.add("complited"); //add class "complited" to span
     li.appendChild(span); //put span as li child
     ul.appendChild(li); // put li as ul child
     li.appendChild(button1);
     button1.classList.add("buttonli");
        button1.value("Delete"); // here I've got error "button1.value is not a function"
     li.classList.add("clickable"); //asign "clickable" class to li
     input.value = "";
}
```

```html
<ul id="ul1">
  <li class="bold red clickable" random="23"><span class="complited">Notebook</span><button class="buttonli">Delete</button></li>
  <li class="clickable"><span class="complited">Jello</span> <button class="buttonli">Delete</button></li>
  <li class="clickable"><span class="complited">Spinach</span> <button class="buttonli">Delete</button></li>
  <li class="clickable"><span class="complited">Rice</span> <button class="buttonli">Delete</button></li>
  <li class="clickable"><span class="complited">Birthday Cake</span> <button class="buttonli">Delete</button></li>
  <li class="clickable"><span class="complited">Candles</span> <button class="buttonli">Delete</button></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: `button1.value("Delete"); // here I've got error "button1.value is not a function"` You get the error, because it is not a function, its a property. Try `button1.value = "Delete";` and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> button1.value("Delete"); // here I've got error "button1.value is not a function"
> ```

No, it's a simple accessor property.

```
button1.value = "Delete"
```

… but it sets the value that will be submitted when the button is used to submit a form. It **doesn't** set the display text, which is the content *inside the button element*.

That's why you wrote:

> ```
> <button class="buttonli">Delete</button>
> ```

and not:

```
<button class="buttonli" value="Delete"></button>
```

So create a text node and put it inside the button:

```
const button_text = document.createTextNode("Delete");
button1.appendChild(button_text);
```

Comment: What about button1.textContent = "Delete"?

Answer (score 0):

```
function createListElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var span = document.createElement("span"); //create span
  var button1 = document.createElement("button"); //create 
  var ul = document.getElementById("ul1"); //ul 
  var input = document.createElement("input"); //ul 
  span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value)); //assign value to span
  span.classList.add("complited"); //add class "complited" to span
  li.appendChild(span); //put span as li child
  ul.appendChild(li); // put li as ul child
  li.appendChild(button1);
  button1.classList.add("buttonli");
  button1.innerHTML = "Delete"; //Because you are using a <button> instead of <input type="button">, you need to set the innerHTML
  li.classList.add("clickable"); //asign "clickable" class to li
  input.value = "";
}
```

That is because you are using a  instead of  therefore you need to set the innerHTML.
[Check this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542000/setting-a-buttons-value-using-javascript)

Check the fiddle bellow. 
[Jsfiddle with solution](https://jsfiddle.net/vfogb0t6/)