# Change the text of a button using another button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, arrays

```js
function change_text(){
//change the cat word to dog word.
}
```

```html
<button id="button_1_id" >Cat</button>



<br><br><br><br>

<button id="chnage_text_button" >Change the Text of Above Button</button>
```

I want to use a button to change the button text of another button. May I ask how to accomplish this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting a button's value using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542000/setting-a-buttons-value-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Theodore John Please check below code for your issue. it's a basic Jq. if you want to change anything on clicking so you need to create click function and add some events.

```js
$('#chnage_text_button').click(function () {
    $('#button_1_id').text('Dog');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button_1_id" >Cat</button>



<br><br><br><br>

<button id="chnage_text_button">Change the Text of Above Button</button>
```